# How To Redirect Before Checking for SSL?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-14.04

I have an SSL certificate for my domain, let's call it `example.com`. 
Also I have another domain, let's call it example.net

When I get HTTPS requests for domain `example.net` it fails but `example.com` it works. I want to redirect HTTPS requests for `example.net` to `https://example.com`.

Notice: they are both hosted on the same server (Ubuntu 14.04 - Apache 2.4). I tried a CNAME record for example.net to redirect it to example.com but also fails (my browser tell's me that the certificate is vaild only for `example.com`).

So what to do? Do I have to get another SSL certificate for `example.net`?

Comment: With letsencrypt there is no need to worry anymore about the cost of getting a certificate for each and every domain you have and operate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix missing ssl-cert for subdomain www. using redirect or similar](http://serverfault.com/questions/745967/fix-missing-ssl-cert-for-subdomain-www-using-redirect-or-similar)

Comment: While the duplicate I've linked to above talks about a subdomain, the same answer is valid for a different TLD as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want both sites to support HTTPS, including a mere redirect, you need both to have valid certificates.

There is no way to bypass this as it is part of the well-thought mechanism that protects the user from being led to the wrong site.

Comment: what about getting a cert for my ip because the websites are hosted on same server ?!

Comment: Because no visitor is coming to your site(s) by entering  https://<ip-address> as the URL and the URL a needs to match the certificate.

Comment: @IamPublic:  I don't see where the issue comes from as certificates cost next to nothing anyways and if you need both domains to work, you need two certificates, period.